# List with two values to two different string variables

Tags: c#, listview

i need your help

i have a listview

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(myReader["Date"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(myReader["AnnualPrice"].ToString())


Date        Price
112/9/1990   15.30
12/9/1990   15.30 
12/9/1990   15.30
12/9/1990   15.30
```

and i want to put those two values in a separate String variables in order to use them in a method that accepts two string variables.

Could you help me pls?

**UPDATE**

now i am here but i still receive the same error.

Could you please tell me am i doing something wrong?

```
 try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                var date = String.Format("{0,20}", myReader["Date"].ToString());
                var AnnualPrice = String.Format("{0,20}", myReader["AnnualPrice"].ToString());

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(date + "," + AnnualPrice);

                //var date = String.Format("{0,20}", myReader["Date"].ToString());
                //var AnnualPrice = String.Format("{0,20}", myReader["AnnualPrice "].ToString());

                RPlot(date, AnnualPrice);

                }//end while 


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }






    }
    //Method to plot data
    public void RPlot(string var1, string Var2)
    {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        // REngine requires explicit initialization.
        // You can set some parameters.
        engine.Initialize();
        String RCommand = "plot(" + var1 + "," + Var2 + ")";
        engine.Evaluate(RCommand.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: `string.Format("{0}#{1}",myReader["Date"],myReader["AnnualPrice"])` Do you want this?

Comment: how to invoke this line in my method? public void RPlot(String var1, String Var2)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your items and then get the value and subitem[0] value and pass them.